# C++: Convert arg[0] to a wchar_t

Tags: c++, argv

I am fairly new to C++ and am creating a project which sets your desktop wallpaper to whatever file you put in the directory. To get the current directory I am using argv[0]. This is, however, not returning the correct type to set the desktop wallpaper. Here is what I have.

```
cout << argv[0] // btw, argv[0] returns the correct thing
const wchar_t* path = L"C:\\blahblahblah"; // i just want to be able to set this to the argv[0] while keeping the type so i can later set the wallpaper
SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (void *)path, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE); // works fine
```

Basically, I want to set the wallpaper to argv[0] (obviously handle the string)

Comment: You may also be interested in `SystemParametersInfoA` which does not need the conversion.

Comment: Or since you seem to be targeting only windows, you can use the wide char version of main they provide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/c-language/using-wmain?view=msvc-160